# redux fetchs store data with delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

I'm new to redux and I'm trying to implement redux for my first project. everything looks fine but when i console.log the data from redux store, it gives me two empty array at first and then in the next lines array isn't empty. this causes map function not to work on my ProductCart element.

console:

```
BikesPage.js:22 []length: 0[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
BikesPage.js:22 []length: 0[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
BikesPage.js:22 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
BikesPage.js:22 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: {_id: '6351a9a95814ff5815e61187', title: 'MTB', price: '500', __v: 0}1: {_id: '6351aa75f685aa64faeaf27d', category: 'bike', title: 'MTB', price: '5080', __v: 0}2: {_id: '6351aa96f685aa64faeaf27f', category: 'bike5', title: 'MTB', price: '3980', __v: 0}length: 3[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
BikesPage.js:22 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: {_id: '6351a9a95814ff5815e61187', title: 'MTB', price: '500', __v: 0}1: {_id: '6351aa75f685aa64faeaf27d', category: 'bike', title: 'MTB', price: '5080', __v: 0}2: {_id: '6351aa96f685aa64faeaf27f', category: 'bike5', title: 'MTB', price: '3980', __v: 0}length: 3[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
BikesPage.js:22 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
BikesPage.js:22 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
BikesPage.js:22 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
BikesPage.js:22 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
BikesPage.js:22 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  products: [],
};

export const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ALL:
      return { ...state, products: [...action.payload] };
    case CREATE:
      return [state.products, action.payload];
    case UPDATE:
      return state.products.map((product) =>
        product._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : product
      );
    case DELETE:
      return state.products.filter((product) => product._id !== action.payload);

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

combine reducers :

```
export const reducers = combineReducers({ products: productReducer });
```

action:

```
export const getProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.fetchProducts();
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_ALL, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

bike page component :

```
function BikesPage() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const product = useSelector((state) => state.products);
  const { products } = product;

  console.log(products);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <div className="BikesPage">
            {(products.length > 0) &
              products.map((p) => {
                return <ProductCart price={p.price} title={p.title} />;
              })}
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

index.js file:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

to solve this problem i'v even written the useEffect funvtion in app.js to dispatch getProducts() but it still doesn't work

Comment: It is okay that at first render products array is empty. But what do you mean saying map is not working?

Comment: @AvetikNersisyan i mean because the array is empty map doesn't work on that empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write double `&&` not `&`

```
  {(products.length > 0) &&
              products.map((p) => {
                return <ProductCart price={p.price} title={p.title} />;
              })}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my time a lot!